# Selenium IDE - local (non-webhosted) file access for testing?

Tags: file, selenium-ide

**My Problem**

When Selenium IDE is used to run a test, the "Base URL" is always accessed via http on some web server.

I need to know if (and how) its possible to get Selenium IDE to run a test on a locally stored file. When opening a file in Firefox, the path looks something like this in the Address Bar: file:///C:/Documents and Settings/username/My Documents/somehtml.html

However, Selenium gives a nasty error when I put this path in the Selenium IDE's Base URL field for my test (See bottom of my post).

**What I tried**

I run Windows XP and have tried switching the file path slashes to backslashes while keeping the protocol (file:///) slashes as is. I tried replacing spaces with %20 too.

I also considered whether my Firefox proxy settings might be causing an issue, but it isn't because if i open the file in Firefox it does so without issue.

The solution I'm working on is to avoid Selenium WebDriver at this phase. I know it is better on a technical but there are practical reasons why I can't use that at this point. Selenium IDE must be used for now.

**Error**

Error thrown when attempting to open local file:

> [error] Unexpected Exception: name -> NS_ERROR_FAILURE, QueryInterface
>   -> function QueryInterface() { [native code] }, message -> Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMLocation.href], result -> 2147500037, filename ->
>   chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js,
>   lineNumber -> 686, columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame ::
>   chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js
>   :: BrowserBot.prototype.setOpenLocation :: line 686, inner -> null,
>   data -> null, initialize -> function initialize() { [native code] }

Comment: I don't know how to get around this error (someone will probably come along and tell you) but if you can't, I must mention the nuclear option for completeness: make a local tomcat and serve the file through that. that way, you can access it via http://localhost:8080/somehtml.html which I imagine selenium will like.

Comment: Thanks jimp this helped. I decided to use XAMPP instead as I prefer Apache. I'd love to mark yours as the accepted answer or vote it up somehow but for some reason your answer/comment is separated from the section on the page that DOES allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

open `about:config` then change `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false`. enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Selenium IDE icon in the upper right of the browser window. Select "Manage Extensions" from the context menu. Toggle on "Allow access to file URLs" in the settings dialog.

This works in Chrome/Windows 10 and Version 3.17.0 of Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the open command as the first line in your test, and set the local path as the target. This is fine for a handful of tests, but may not be sufficient for larger test suites.

```
command: open
target: file///c:/path/to/your/file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just solved it. Here is how:

1. Remove the base url.
2. Enter open or openWindow in command
3. Enter the file url in target e.g. file:///C:/temp/junk/SomeSiteAutomation/ABC.htm

Worked for me on FF 26 and Selenium 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Open Selenium IDE - chrome extension
As soon as we open it will ask for project name and project url - just cancel it
Go to selenium IDE

[image]

In selenium IDE - in "command" text box select "open"
in "target" text box enter the path to sample html file as below
"file:///D:/index2.html"
Then this will show up in the command, target and value columns of the selenium ide.
Now just run the test. This will open up the local html file

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I'm using Ubuntu and apache, but on Windows you can do the same.

1. move your *index.html* to `/var/www/html` (localhost points per default to this folder)
2. use *http://127.0.0.1* as base_url in selenium ide